# Browning and dying lotus leaves

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care

[image]

Outside pot in Santa Clara County California. Lotus is about 8 years old and has done fine up to this year. Now every single leaf gets brown around the edges, then gradually gets totally brown from outer edges to the middle, and dies.